# Why is the customer account is not deleted in this code

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying add the **Delete My Account** functionality for the users in the site.There I used the following code and its execution does not results in any error.

```
public function deleteAction()
    {
        $id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId‌​();
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);
        Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);    
        $customer->delete();
        $this->_getSession()->logout()
            ->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl());
        $this->_redirect('/');
    }
```

But it does not delete the customer account.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$customer->setIsDeleteable(true)` before DELETE method.

Comment: It didn`t work for me

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
public function deleteAction()
{
    $session = $this->_getSession();
    $sessCustomer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
    $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
    // load by customer id
    $customer->load($sessCustomer->getId());
    try {
        Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);
        $customer->delete();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```